# How to retrive all child elements of a root child with values in firebase realtime database

Tags: android

I 'm trying to retrive all Posts(Root child) data..using datasnapshot along with Map.....

but only Problem is- a single entry data is repeated

others entries are not shown..i don't know why?

i think some mistakes occuring here..

pleae help me out, thanks!

My code looks like-

```
mPostDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot!=null) {
            Map<String,Object> all_users_IDs=(HashMap<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            //iterate through each user, ignoring their UID
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : all_users_IDs.entrySet()){
                //Get single user map
                Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
                String date= (String) singleUser.get("Date");
                String posted_img= (String) singleUser.get("PostedImage");
                String desc= (String) singleUser.get("Description");
                holder.setPostedImg(posted_img, getContext());
                holder.setDate(date);
                holder.setDescription(desc);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     // code here
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation.